# Passing .FindOne() result to variable for gridView - C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, variables, gridview

I am using a directory search in a C# .NEt web page code behind.  I do not know how to have the result added to the text of a cell.  The results that are shown in column is the text "System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult".  I supect that I am not passing the attribute correctly when I add the result to string.

```
String Name = userName;
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher();
ds.Filter = "samaccountname=" + Name;
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userAccountControl");
SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();
e.Row.Cells[5].Text = sr.ToString();
```

As you can see, I am passing sr.ToString() to the cell.  This seems to be incorrect but I do not know how else to pass the result to a variable that I can then convert to string. I evne tried this:

```
var result1 = sr;
string result2 = result1.ToString();
e.Row.Cells[5].Text = result2;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the msdn site on [SearchResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresult.aspx). It looks like you want to set it to `sr.Path`?  There is no overload for `ToString()` so it's just going to return the default for the object.

Comment: using "e.Row.Cells[5].Text = sr.Path;" returns the LDAP path.  I need the userAccountControl to tell if the user is disabled.  Using "e.Row.Cells[5].Text = sr.userAccountControl;" does not work as the editor sees it as an error "System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult" does not contain a definition for it.

Comment: You're going to have to look at what's in `sr.Properties`, which is a dictionary of extra properties.

Answer (score 0):

In the SearchResult - try something like `sr["userAccountControl"].ToString()`.  The search result object is just an object.  You have to tell what property to load out of it's collection.  You can check `PropertyNames` property to see what's in the result object.  Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.resultpropertycollection.aspx
for a reference of the object you are working with.

Comment: A little digging and I was able to get it.

Comment: `    String name = userName;
    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher();
    ds.Filter = "sAMAccountName=" + name;
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userAccountControl");
    SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();
    DirectoryEntry dsresult = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
    e.Row.Cells[5].Text = dsresult.Properties["userAccountControl"][0].ToString(); `